# One public key multiple private keys

Tags: c#, cryptography

I have an application which I want to build some licensing operation for. The idea is to have a key on my side and offer private keys for users. So there is a key on my side which can be encoded into some other keys and in application's side it can detect if these keys are valid or not. So the relation between these two keys are one to many. I wanted to ask if you have any leads to do this in c-sharp.
Thanks

Comment: Try searching for **certificate-based authentication**.

Comment: This is going to depend on exactly what you're trying to protect from who (which isn't very clear).  The RSA PKI cryptography used by certificates can mathematically only have one private key per public key (and vice versa).

Comment: The scheme sounds a little unusual. In cases like these - with the *"use case"* being *"encrypt with the private key"* - you usually want a Probabilistic Signature Scheme with Recovery (PSSR). You sign the license with your private key and then provide it to the client. The client verifies the signature with your public key and recovers the license from the signature.